# Python/Pytest variable value is updated on each parameterise execution

Tags: python, json, pytest

I am new to Pytest, below is my query.
I'm trying to add a negative automation test cases to the following API using Pytest,
I have an API request data as below

```
variables.py
-----------------
myrequest_data = { 
 "name" : "Test User",
 "age" : "20",
 "city" : "Bengaluru"
}

negative_values = ["123456", "@$%$Dev", "xsdcsv", "-4565432", "45f"]
key_list = ["name", "age", "city"]
```

And below is my test case file,

```
test_person_api.py
--------------------
class TestPersonAPI:

   @pytest.mark.parametrize("request_key", variables.key_list)
   @pytest.mark.parametrize("negative_values", variables.negative_values)
   def test_person_api_negative_verification(self, request_key, negative_values):
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        url = "http://person-api-request-url/endpoint"
        variables.myrequest_data[request_key] = negative_values
        response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(req), headers=headers)
        print("Response:----->>" + response.text)
        assert response.status_code == 400
```

So my code is supposed to update the negative value for each json key from my variable `myrequest_data` on each execution, for example,

```
TC1[123456-name]
TC2[123456-age]
TC3[123456-city]
TC4[@$%$Dev-name]
TC5[@$%$Dev-age]
TC6[@$%$Dev-city]
TC7[xsdcsv-name]
TC8[xsdcsv-age]
TC9[xsdcsv-city]
.
.
.
[and so on...]
```

But, for the above test case `myrequest_data` variable is updated and saved on each execution, so the variable is not freshly retreived from the file.
Like in the below example console log, for every test case executed the previously set json key-value is still available. By the end of TC3 all the keys have the negative value `12345` set to them.

```
TC1 - 
payload --->> { "name": "123456", "age": "20", "city": "Bengaluru" }

TC2 - 
payload --->> { "name": "123456", "age": "123456", "city": "Bengaluru" }

TC3 -
payload --->> { "name": "123456", "age": "123456", "city": "123456" }

[and so on...]
```

Whereas, i need a new data for each execution, **below is the desired result i want**.
On each execution the payload should be retrieved from the variable as it is and the negative value `12345` should be set to the respective keys only.

```
TC1 - 
payload --->> { "name": "123456", "age": "20", "city": "Bengaluru" }

TC2 - 
payload --->> { "name": "Test User", "age": "123456", "city": "Bengaluru" }

TC3 -
payload --->> { "name": "Test User", "age": "20", "city": "123456" }

[and so on...]
```

Please help me with this issue, i have tried a lot to resolve this

Comment: variables.request_data is imported into the scope once and then remains the same object during execution of the test (for all parameters). Since you modify it in the test it gets updated for each run of the test with different parameters. If you want to reuse it but reset it on each instance of the test (with a certain parameter) there are several ways. E.g.,you can use request = copy.deepcopy(variables.request_data) and then use request[request_key] = negative_values or you can create a fixture (see the pytest docs on that).

Comment: I tried the fixture way, it worked for me. Thank you